# C# one event for multi textbox

Tags: c#, events, textbox

I have textbox4 = textbox1 + textbox2 + textbox3 . i want when textbox1 or textbox2 or textbox3 changed textbox4 auto show value.
I have code:

```
 private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            textbox4.Text = ((float.Parse(textbox1.Text) + float.Parse(textbox2.text)+ float.Parse(textbox3.text)).ToString();

        }
        catch 
        {

        }

    }
 private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
           textbox4.Text = ((float.Parse(textbox1.Text) + float.Parse(textbox2.text)+ float.Parse(textbox3.text)).ToString();

        }
        catch 
        {

        }

    }
 private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
           textbox4.Text = ((float.Parse(textbox1.Text) + float.Parse(textbox2.text)+ float.Parse(textbox3.text)).ToString();

        }
        catch 
        {

        }

    }
```

Now I want to make it simpler. Shorten the code. Only declare the action 1 time.
Like: textbox1 or textbox2 or textbox3 changes the tense textbox4 = textbox1 + textbox2 + textbox3

Comment: So, What is the question ?!

Comment: You can easliy achieve that by doing only 1 Event and attaching this event to 3 Textboxes, if you are using VIsualStudio then on the properties click on the events button at the top for every textbox choose the same event

Comment: yes, I tried it and it worked, now I want to add another separate event for textbox1 in addition to the other one when it's TextChanged. What I have to do

Comment: ok . I did it. I use IF in the event. Thank ALL for help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by doing:

1) Write an new method for the event like this:

```
private void UpdateTextOnTextBox(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
     textbox4.Text = ((float.Parse(textbox1.Text) + float.Parse(textbox2.text)+ float.Parse(textbox3.text)).ToString();

   }
   catch (Exeption ex)
   {
     textbox4.Text = ex.Message;
   }

}
```

2) Delete Previous Methods and leave only the new one

3) Re-attach the event for every textboxes (Property Window>Events>on TextChanged choose: `UpdateTextOnTextBox`

Enjoy

Comment: I am using WPF, I tried your way but could not find the TextChanged event in the window of the Property Window. there is a problem, I think if using this method it will work even if I use a textbox other than the other this 4 textboxes.

Comment: oh. I understand. But if so, force all 3 textboxes to do the same thing exactly when textchange. If I want to do a few different things in textchange, like: Textbox1 change it has in common textbox4 = textbox1 + textbox2 + textbox3 in addition to the formula textbox5 = textbox1 + textbox2

Answer (score 0):

I would make the first three textboxes share a TextChangedEventHandler and set textBox4 to IsReadOnly=True in this case.

```
private void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        float float1 = 0, float2 = 0, float3 = 0;
        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, float1) && 
            float.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out float2) && 
            float.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out float3)) 
        {
            textBo4.Text = (float1 + float2 + float3).ToString();
        }
        else 
        {
            textBox4.Text = "";
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
        textBox4.Text = "";
    }
}
```